# How to add movie trailer to Google search page

Tags: google-chrome, nuxt.js

My website provide movie content, it is build by Nuxtjs 2.

I am trying to add a trailer for my movie when it is shown on Google Search Page (tab Video), like when you search for a movie name on Google, it will show the list of search result, each result have a movie trailer under the link. When user hover thumbnail, the trailer will be played.

[image]

But I don't know where to start from. I don't know this is implemented inside my codes or it would be configured somewhere on Google. I can't find any document of Google for instruction on this as well.

I would be very grateful for any advice. Thank you.